# Dynamic schema vs flexible schema vs dynamic mapping vs schema-less

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, nosql, couchbase, database-schema

I am learning about Couchbase at the moment, and one of its key concepts is that it has a [*dynamic schema*](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/data-modeling/concepts-data-modeling-intro.html#story-h2-2).

> In Couchbase, when we refer to a schema we refer to the way the application structures its documents. As opposed to traditional RDBMS, schemas in Couchbase are entirely defined and managed by the application.

In MongoDB, you have a [*flexible schema*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/), which "allow dynamic modification of the schema without downtime or performance impact."

In Elasticsearch, you have [*dynamic mapping*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html), which is the "automatic detection and addition of new types and fields" to the current mapping.

Dynamic schema, flexible schema, dynamic mapping all just sounds like having a schemaless database. Are they all equivalent? Or are there small caveats that distinguishes one from another?

Answer (score -1):

I would say at the level you are exploring, yes -- they are all equivalent.  All permit "the data to do the talking" i.e. there is no requirement to predefine field names and types, and tables/collections can have "rows" (or documents in MongoDB, etc.) of structures that can be very different from row to row within the same collection.

Beyond this, there are performance and use case and scaling and language driver differences amongst these products.